# The specified child already has a parent Exception

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-fragments

I'm using `Fragments` in my code since `TabActivity` is deprecated but I'm getting this error in my `Logcat`:

```
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1871)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1828)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1808)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
07-09 09:19:40.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5935):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Here is the code where I add the tabs:**

```
public class RelatorioPontos extends FragmentActivity {

     private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
     private String id;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.relatorio_layout);
            mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

            id = getIntent().getStringExtra("idPonto");

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("id", id);

            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("dados").setIndicator("Dados"), DadosPonto.class, args);
            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("analises").setIndicator("Análises"), AnalisesPonto.class, args);
            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("multimidia").setIndicator("Multimídia"), ArquivosMultimidia.class, args);
        }


}
```

**Here is the first tab class:**

```
public class DadosPonto extends Fragment{

    Ponto ponto = new Ponto();
    private String id;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        id = getArguments().getString("id");

        PontoDAO pdao = new PontoDAO(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        ponto = pdao.retornaPonto(id);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dados_ponto_layout, container, false);

        View idPonto = view.findViewById(R.id.idPonto);
        View idUser = view.findViewById(R.id.idUser);
        View pontoNome = view.findViewById(R.id.nomePonto);
        View dtCampo = view.findViewById(R.id.dtCampo);
        View projeto = view.findViewById(R.id.projeto);
        View UTMEste = view.findViewById(R.id.utmEste);
        View UTMNorte = view.findViewById(R.id.utmNorte);
        View UTMFuso = view.findViewById(R.id.utmFuso);
        View UTMHemisferio = view.findViewById(R.id.utmHemisferio);
        View latDec = view.findViewById(R.id.latDec);
        View longDec = view.findViewById(R.id.longDec);
        View altitude = view.findViewById(R.id.altitude);
        View localidade = view.findViewById(R.id.localidade);
        View outrasUG = view.findViewById(R.id.outrasUG);
        View descPonto = view.findViewById(R.id.descPonto);
        View complemento = view.findViewById(R.id.complemento);
        View equipe = view.findViewById(R.id.equipe);
        View fonteUG = view.findViewById(R.id.fonteUG);

        ((TextView) idPonto).setText("Id do ponto: " + ponto.getIdPonto());
        ((TextView) idUser).setText("Id do usuário: " + ponto.getIdUsuario()+"");
        ((TextView) pontoNome).setText("Nome do ponto: " + ponto.getPontoNome());
        ((TextView) dtCampo).setText("Data do campo: " + ponto.getDtCampo());
        ((TextView) projeto).setText("Projeto: " + ponto.getProjeto()+"");
        ((TextView) UTMEste).setText("UTM Este: " + String.valueOf(ponto.getUTMEste()));
        ((TextView) UTMNorte).setText("UTM Norte: " + String.valueOf(ponto.getUTMNorte()));
        ((TextView) UTMFuso).setText("UTM Fuso: " + ponto.getUTMFuso()+"");
        ((TextView) UTMHemisferio).setText("UTM Hemisfério: " + ponto.getUTMHemisferio());
        ((TextView)latDec).setText("Latitude decimal: " + String.valueOf(ponto.getLatDec()));
        ((TextView)longDec).setText("Longitude decimal: " + String.valueOf(ponto.getLongDec()));
        ((TextView)altitude).setText("Altitude: " + ponto.getAltitude()+"");
        ((TextView)localidade).setText("Localidade: " + ponto.getLocalidade());
        ((TextView)outrasUG).setText("Outras Unidades Geológicas: " + ponto.getOutrasUG());
        ((TextView)descPonto).setText("Descrição do ponto: " + ponto.getDescPonto());
        ((TextView)complemento).setText("Complemento da descrição: " + ponto.getComplement());
        ((TextView)equipe).setText("Equipe: " + ponto.getEquipe());
        ((TextView)fonteUG).setText("Fonte da Unidade Geológica: " + ponto.getFonteUG());

        return view;
    }
}
```

**And the second tab activity:**

```
public class AnalisesPonto extends ListFragment {

    private ArrayList<AnaliseEstrutural> analises;
    AnalisesDAO andao;
    String idPonto;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        idPonto = getArguments().getString("id");



        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        View lista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.analises_ponto_layout, container, false);

        //ListView analisesList = (ListView) lista.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        View analisesList = (ListView) lista.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        andao = new AnalisesDAO(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        analises = andao.relatorioAnalises(idPonto);

        AnalisesAdapter analisesAdapter = new AnalisesAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        for(int j = 0; j < analises.size(); j++) {
            analisesAdapter.add(analises.get(j));
        }

        return analisesList;
    }       
}
```

The third class code is the same as the second one so I'll not post here, the first tab works well but when I enter in the second one I get this exception.

My doubt is how I can deal with this Exception?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most probably you are getting this exception when a configuration change occurs, for example a screen orientation. It complains that the view is still attached to the previous view hierarchy, and so you need to remove it and re-attach it to the current one.

```
public class DadosPonto extends Fragment{

    // Keep a reference to the view; 
    private View view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dados_ponto_layout, container, false);
            View idPonto = view.findViewById(R.id.idPonto);
            // .....
        } else {
            // If we are returning from a configuration change:
            // "view" is still attached to the previous view hierarchy
            // so we need to remove it and re-attach it to the current one
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            parent.removeView(view);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: should I put this same condition in all the other classes too?

Comment: I'd like to add that this issue was causing errors for me ONLY on API level 10 using the v4 support library.  Not sure if the cause is some other bug in my code, but I'm now checking the inflated viewgroup for a parent before returning the view